# Mysql Null value not included in result

Tags: php, mysql

In a mysql table I have an enum type column tread ('Y','I','N','D') default Null. When I retrieve data from table and put condition on that column like tread!='D' then the columns that have Null values are not included in result.

Comment: Care to add some code, table schema, test data. Take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) to know how to write a good question. Also Jon Skeet has an [useful post on his blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) about the subject

Answer (score 3):

because null values must be treated apart

```
where tread <> 'D' or tread is null
```

[working with null](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/working-with-null.html)

or you can "transform" the null values before equality test:

ANSI version ([coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce))

```
where COALESCE(tread, ' ') <> 'D'
```

mysql only ([IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull))

```
where IFNULL(tread, ' ') <> 'D'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way of doing this

```
where not ifnull(tread, '-1') ='D'
```